# Cant use values from (fetched) context(provider) as input to my useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-context

**Short version:**

I have a useEffect in a ContextProvider where I fetch some data from server. In my component I
use this Context and want to init another useState()-hook with the "incoming" data. The value in
[value, setValue] = useState(dataFromContext) does not get set/inited with dataFromContext. Why, oh why?

**The very long version:**

Im trying to follow (and expand on) [this example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-context-with-react-hooks-5591a4010689) of how to use context/useContext-hook in react

So, I have an AppContext and a ContextProvider, I wrap my  in  in index.js, everything in the example works nice.

Now I want to load data in useEffect inside my ContextProvider, so my context provider now looks like this

```html
const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const profileInfoUrl = BASE_URL + `users/GetCurrentUsersProfileInfo/`
  const {loading, getTokenSilently} = useAuth0();  

  const [profileInfo, setProfileInfo] = useState( {})


  useEffect(() => {          
    if (!loading && profileInfo.user.username  === '' ) {                 
        Communication.get(profileInfoUrl, getTokenSilently, setProfileInfo); 
    }
 },[loading, getTokenSilently])
 
  
  const context = {
    profileInfo,
    setProfileInfo
  };
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={ context }> 
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now, in my component, I want to display this data. One of them is users selected categories, a list of an id and isSelected, which should feed a checkboxlist.

```html
const TsProfileSettingsPage = ( ) => {
  //..  
  const { profileInfo, setProfileInfo } = useContext(AppContext);  
  const userCategories = Object.assign({}, ...profileInfo.userDetails.categories.map((c) => ({[c.id]: c})));
  const [checkedCategories, setCheckedCategories] = useState(userCategories);
 
  console.log("profileInfo.userDetails.categories : " + JSON.stringify(profileInfo.userDetails.categories));   
  console.log("userCategories : " + JSON.stringify(userCategories));//correct dictionary
  console.log("checkedCategories : " + JSON.stringify(checkedCategories)); //empty object!
 //...rest of code
```

So I load users selection and converts is to a dictionary that ends up in "userCategories". I use that "userCategories" to init checkedCategories. BUT, from the console.logs below, userCategories is set correctly, but checkedCategories is not, its becomes an empty object!

So my question is. Am I thinking wrong here? (obviously I am), I just want to have an external state.
Everything loads ok, but when I use it to init a useState() in my component it does not get set. I have tested to have another useEffect() in my component, but I just get the feeling that Im doing something more basic error.

Thanks for any help

Comment: useState is only called in the initial render, you are passing userCategories, (which is derived from profileInfo(initally null or whatever value)), as the initial state. try set the checkedCategories manually with useEffect, when userCategories  is updated

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip and clarification. I was testing useEffect() in my component, but got an infinite loop :D, but Im sure I just had an invalid dependant. If this is the way to go I will certainly test this and think a bit.